# Counting Number of New Messages with COUNT function?

Tags: php, mysql, count, message

I'm trying to get the number of new messages a user has from my table ptb_messages where 'read' is set to '0'

Can someone please show me where i'm going wrong.

My table looks like this:

```
id | from_user_id | to_user_id | subject | content | date_sent | read

1         2              4        hello     hello    2012-04-13    0
```

I'm using this function to try  and display the number of unread messages a user has.

```
function check_new_messages() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT('read') FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND ('read)'='0'";
            $check_new_messages_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_new_messages_set);
            return $check_new_messages_set;     
        }

<?php

$check_new_messages_set = check_new_messages();
while ($new = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_messages_set)) {

echo "There are ". $new['COUNT(read)'] ." items.";

}

 ?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION is a super global so... global is pointless on that one

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to `COUNT` that field at all; the `WHERE` is enough. The quotes are just a little off is all:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `read` = 0";
```

Also, please don't use the `mysql_` extensions; they're deprecated in PHP 5.5, and introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities easily. Give prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi a go!

Comment: I would also mention that its better to supply an alias for the count result instead of accessing like `$row['COUNT(*)']`. Its much eaiser to read. `SELECT COUNT(*) as msgcount FROM ...` then access with `$row['msgcount']`

Comment: thanks but i get this error with that: Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 0' at line 1

Comment: @MarkTaylor: I guess `read` is a reserved word. Backtick it: ```AND `read` = 0```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(read) FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND read = 0";
```

You might also want to read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think your SQL might need a tweak:

```
SELECT COUNT('read') FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND ('read)'='0'
```

Shouldn’t it be:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `read` = 0
```

Then this line:

```
echo "There are ". $new['COUNT(read)'] ." items.";
```

should be:

```
echo "There are ". $new[0] ." items.";
```

Comment: i've tried the changes you suggested but i get this error still: Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 0' at line 1

Comment: You need to make ensure that `$_SESSION['user_id']` is never empty() and is_numeric() otherwise your SQL will fail. See also @minitech about back ticking read.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you do need to look into Mysqli or PDO, that being said, it is obvious that you will have different states of the column "read'. 0= unread, 1=read, etc....

Here you can make your function more generic and allow you to get those states with one function. Something like this:

```
function check_new_messages($id,$state)
{
    $query ="SELECT COUNT(*)as newmessage FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$id." AND `read` ='".$state."'";
    $check_new_messages_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($check_new_messages_set);
    return $check_new_messages_set;     
 }
    $check_new_messages_set = check_new_messages($_SESSION['user_id'], '0' );
    while ($new = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_messages_set))
        {
            echo "There are ". $new['newmessage'] ." items.";
        }
```

Here is an example using MYSQLI. In this example you can return the row count and echo it:

```
function check_new_messages($id,$state)
{
    $MessageCount = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($MessageCount->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $MessageCount->connect_errno . ") " . $MessageCount->connect_error;
        $MessageCount->close();
    }
    $values = $MessageCount->query("SELECT to_user_id FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id =".$id." AND `read` ='".$state."'");
    if($count = $values->num_rows)
    {
        return $count;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

//return call like this

```
$Unread = check_new_messages($_SESSION['user_id'], '0' );
echo "There are ". $Unread ." items.";
```